# How can I call a method inherited from an interface directly from a class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface, implementation

```
using System;

interface ISample{
  abstract void SampleMethod();
}

class SampleClass: ISample{
  void ISample.SampleMethod(){
    Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod was called.");
  }
}

class Program{
  public static void Main (string[] args){
    SampleClass smpcls = new SampleClass();
    smpcls.ISample.SampleMethod();
  }
}
```

This code works seamlessly. But I must call "ISample" interface from "smpcls" which is the instance of "SampleClass". How can I call "SampleMethod" directly from a instance of "SampleClass"?

For example:

```
...
SampleClass smpcls = new SampleClass();
smpcls.SampleMethod() //I would like to call it like this.
smpcls.ISample.SampleMethod() //Not like this
...
```

Comment: you can't have an abstract method in an interface

Comment: If the method is implemented like that, you will have to cast the class instance to the interface before accessing that method. Instead, why not just make it a public method instead of explicitly implementing that method of the interface?

Comment: When they added default interface methods in C# 8, they also added support for explicit access modifiers. Although `abstract` is the default, you can in fact specify it explicitly now. It doesn't change anything though, the member behaves like it has been behaving since C# 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SampleClass [explicitly implements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation#:%7E:text=Explicit%20Interface%20Implementation%20%28C%23%20Programming%20Guide%29%20If%20a,interfaces%20to%20use%20that%20member%20as%20their%20implementation.) ISample.SampleMethod, which is not what you want. Simply change it to

```
class SampleClass: ISample{
  void SampleMethod(){
    Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod was called.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't use this

```
void Main()
{
    SampleClass smpcls = new SampleClass();
    smpcls.SampleMethod();
}

public interface ISample
{
    public void SampleMethod();
}

public class SampleClass : ISample
{
    public void SampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod was called.");
    }
}
```

or if have c# 8+  maybe you mean this

```
SampleClass smpcls = new SampleClass();
smpcls.AsISampleMethod();

//or if you don't want to create an extra method

smpcls.AsISample.SampleMethod();


public interface ISample
{
    void SampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod was called.");
    }
}
public class SampleClass : ISample
{
    public ISample AsISample => (ISample)this;

    public void AsISampleMethod()
    {
        AsISample.SampleMethod();
    }
}
```

but the interface works almost the same as an abstract class

Comment: And get rid of the `abstract` modifier on `SampleMethod` in `ISample`. I'm surprised that even compiles

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks. I am agree with you.

Comment: `abstract` is the default modifier for methods in interfaces, you can think of it silently being there all those year. When default interface implementations were added with C# 8, they also allowed explicit modifiers, including abstract. However, the `abstract` modifier, present or not, does not have any impact according to the documentation. It's there for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast it as the interface to access a explicitly implemented interface method

```
ISample smpcls = new SampleClass();
smpcls.SampleMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that when implementing an interface's members there are two ways:

1. implement interface
2. implement interface explicitely

In your example you have selected *implement interface explicitely*.

```
void ISample.SampleMethod()
```

If you use this option, then you are telling the class that the method *void ISample.SampleMethod()* belongs to the interface and NOT to the class.

Why and when can you use explicit option? Well, suppose you have another method in your class which is called exactly *SampleMethod()*
Now, if you implement ISample then you will have a clash with this method as ISample contains a method with the same name. So, to sovle this you use the explicit option on the interface method.

```
public class SampleClass : ISample
{
    void ISample.SampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("interface method");
    }

    public void SampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("class method");
    }
}
```

In your calling code, this is how you call each method:

```
           SampleClass smpcls = new SampleClass();
           smpcls.SampleMethod();
           ((ISample)smpcls).SampleMethod();
```

As you can see: **((ISample)smpcls).SampleMethod();**
this belongs to the interface as you have to cast it to it.

The output from both methods will be as follows:

```
//class method
//interface method
```

If you do not have clashing methods, then use the option "implement interface" which will declare the code without the interface name:

```
public class SampleClass : ISample
{
    public void SampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("now this method belongs to the class");
    }
}
```